# JavaScript: Node cron and node-schedule jobs execute immediately instead of in the future

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron, scheduler, job-scheduling

I am attempting to write a test-script, as part of a larger project which will allow me to schedule future text message alerts. In my script, I try to use both node packages cron and node-schedule. I configure a date object set to three minutes in the future. I use both packages to schedule the job. However, the messages are not sent at the right time, but are sent immediately.

I want my code to execute at a set time in the future, does anyone know why the following code would not work?

```
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
var twilSms = require('./TwilSms');
var schedule = require('node-schedule');

var sendInThree = function(to,message) {
    var threeMinutes = 180000;
    var inThreeMinutes = new Date(Date.now()+threeMinutes);
    process.stdout.write("A text message should be sent at: \n" + inThreeMinutes.toString() + '\n');

    //TRIGGERS INSTANTLY
    var sched = schedule.scheduleJob(inThreeMinutes,twilSms.sendSms(to,
                   ('Did this message arrive at: ' + inThreeMinutes.toString() + '?')));


    //TRIGGERS INSTANTLY
    var cronSMS = new CronJob(inThreeMinutes,
                twilSms.sendSms(to,
                    ('Did this message arrive at: ' + inThreeMinutes.toString() + '?')),
                null, true);
}


sendInThree('13125555555');
```

NOTES:

function twilSms.sendSms() workes as expected in the Node REPL.

I used a fake number only for uploading to SO.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should pass in a callable, e.g. an anonymous function as the second parameter to `CronJob` constructor. In your code, you are passing in the return value of `twilSms.sendSms()` in which case `sendSms()` executes immediately (because it's called by the `()` at the end). It doesn't matter that a function call is a parameter to another function, it executes immediately when the interpreter processes that line.

```
var cronSMS = new CronJob(inThreeMinutes, function() {
                twilSms.sendSms(to,
                    ('Did this message arrive at: ' + inThreeMinutes.toString() + '?')) },
                null, true);
```

**Update 1**

If you don't want to use an anonymous function when specifying the parameters, you can assign a function to a named variable - but it still has to be a callable as `CronJob` expects it to be. E.g.

```
var sendSmsFunc = function() {
    twilSms.sendSms(to,
         ('Did this message arrive at: ' + inThreeMinutes.toString() + '?'))
}

var cronSMS = new CronJob(inThreeMinutes, sendSmsFunc, null, true);
```

The example you have in your 2nd comment doesn't seem right, because although `sendSMS` is a callable in that case, it expects two parameters at runtime. `CronJob` will not pass any parameters so it must be a callable that doesn't expect parameters just simply wants to be called (or executed) at runtime to do its job.

**Update 2**

If you want to be able to pass in parameters to `sendSms()` at the same time when specifying parameters to `CronJob()`, you can use a function that returns a function, e.g.

```
var sendSmsFunc = function(to, message) {
    return function() {
        twilSms.sendSms(to, message);
    }
}

var cronSMS = new CronJob(inThreeMinutes, sendSmsFunc("123", "test message"), null, true);
```

Comment: Thanks so much Macell! Your suggestion did work. Is there a way to avoid wrapping my function within an anonymous function? Any syntactic sugar? Do you have any reading to recommend which explains the difference between a standard function, and making it callable in an anonymous function?

Comment: For example, do you think this should be refactored: var sendSMS = function(to,message) {
    client.messages.create(smsFactoryFromDefault(to,message));
}

module.exports.sendSms = sendSMS;

Comment: Thanks again Marcell, that was all very helpful. I really appreciate your time.